# What did Ligeti mean by 'shimmering effect'?

Tags: history, composers

[Stephen A. Taylor](http://www.mtosmt.org/issues/mto.97.3.3/mto.97.3.3.taylor_frames.html), *Chopin, Pygmies, and Tempo Fugue: Ligeti's "Automne a Varsovie"*, Vol 3.3., Online Journal of the Society for Music Theory.

I looked up ['shimmering'](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/shimmering) on ODO. David Bruce explains this at [2:22](https://youtu.be/svbPKJBJz8I?t=142), but I still don't understand.

> [1.2] He produces these polyrhythms by combining two vastly different sources of inspiration: the Romantic-era piano music of Chopin and Schumann, and the indigenous music of sub-Saharan Africa. The composer writes:
>
> > One often arrives at something qualitatively new by unifying two already known but separate domains. In this case, I have combined two distinct musical ideas: the hemiola of Schumann and Chopin, which depends on meter, and the additive pulsation principle of African music. . . [T]he hemiola arises from the metric ambiguity posed by a measure of six beats, which can either be divided in three groups of two or in two groups of three. . . **The shimmering effect** of dividing the bar simultaneously into two and three produces the metric tension which is one of the most seductive attractions of the music of Chopin, Schumann, Brahms, and Liszt.
> >
> > A completely different metric ambiguity occurs in African music. Here there are no measures in the European sense, but instead two rhythmic levels: a ground layer of fast, even pulsations which are not counted as such but rather felt, and a superimposed, upper layer of occasionally symmetrical, but more often asymmetrical, patterns of varying length.[{1}](http://www.mtosmt.org/issues/mto.97.3.3/mto.97.3.3.taylor_notes.html#FN1)
>
> 1. Gyorgy Ligeti, "On My Etudes for Piano," trans. Sid McLauchlan, *Sonus* 9/1 (1988): 4-5. An abbreviated version appears in the liner notes to Erato Compact Disc ECD 75555.

Comment: You need to start by deciding what "shimmering" means to you for visual effects, then see what sound effects emulate (or synesthesiate, to coin a word) the effect.

Comment: Image-Google "Moiré pattern"; that is basically the graphic equivalent of a polyrhythm, and I guess the word 'shimmer' adequately describes the visual effect.

Comment: Uncle Bob's comment should be an accepted answer.  Especially for 3 against 4, or roulades, that's exactly the optical analogue.

Answer (score 1):

(After some months, nobody else has copied that comment into an answer.)

> Image-Google [Moiré pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=moire+pattern&tbm=isch); that is basically the graphic equivalent of a polyrhythm, and 'shimmer' adequately describes the visual effect.

Especially for 3 against 4, or roulades, that's exactly the optical analogue.

Comment: You're right, maybe it should have been an answer instead of a comment; but I was unsure whether the question was even on-topic.